# Div´s height: 100% does not work

Tags: html, css

I have created a two column layout. [Here is the jsfiddle.net](http://jsfiddle.net/ondra15/oapu11q4/) . My issue is that I want the line in the center with a 10px width to have 100% height. I have created a container `div` with the id `#obal` (`height: auto`). If I set `#cara .inner`'s height to `100%`, the center line disappears. What do I have change?

Thanks for reply.

Comment: Make both columns a lot longer and then hide the extra space with overflow: hidden; to the container http://jsfiddle.net/oapu11q4/3/

Comment: No, I do not want both column same height!

Comment: No need to scream! If you don't want both column same height, then what do you want?! !!!!???

Comment: @JonasGrumann Read the question again, I reworded it for ondra15.

Comment: Thanks Mitch. ondra, you can use the same trick I did just readapt it to work with the line http://jsfiddle.net/oapu11q4/4/

Comment: I want to height div with id="obal" his height is same as height longer column.

Comment: Yes, set up height of `#obal` is solution. But I do not exactly height of longer column mostly. I want to universal solution height

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to horizontally center a div in a div?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/114543/how-to-horizontally-center-a-div-in-a-div)

Comment: did you want to have ID cara > inner div height equal to ID druhy > inner div ? or you want all 3 div's with equal height ?

Comment: @brightboy2004: I do not know that column will be longer. I can not set up height cara > inner as same as druhy > inner. Height of cara I want to have same as height of longer column.

Answer (score 1):

The issue here seems to be that when you set #cara . inner height to 100% it takes the full height of it's parent container - #cara that in this case is 0px;

The solution may look like this:

```css
#obal {
 margin: 10px;
 height: 200px;
} 
#obal #cara {
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    left: -20px;
    height: 100%;
} 
#cara .inner {
    position: absolute;
 height: 100%;
 width: 10px;
    float: left;
 background: #336;
}
div#prvni {
 float: left;
 margin: 0px 30px;
 width: 120px;
 height: 100px;
 background: #ff3322;
 font-size: 0.95rem;
 overflow: hidden;
}  
div#prvni .inner,  div#druhy .inner{  
    padding: 10px;
}
div#druhy {
 width: 120px;
 height: auto;
 background: #393;
 font-size: 1rem;
 overflow: hidden;
    float: left;
}
```

```html
<div id="obal">
    <div id="prvni">
     <div class="inner">Prvni cast text neni sice nejsilnejsi, ale spisovatel se snazi popsat dulezite body jeho navstevy
        </div>
 </div>
 <div id="cara">
     <div class="inner"></div>
 </div>
 <div id="druhy">
     <div class="inner">Druha cast mluvila hlavne o velkych problemech na startu, kdy se vsichni ucastnici nestihnuli pripravit a pote nasledovat zmatek. Jenze kazdy chtel vyhrat, tak to nevzdal <br> NIKDY :-)
         </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

http://jsfiddle.net/oapu11q4/20/

===================== CSS ===================

```
#obal {
        display: table;
        height: auto;
        margin: 10px;
    }
    div#prvni {
        background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #ff3322;
        display: table-cell;
        font-size: 0.95rem;
        height: 100%;
        width: 120px;
    }   

    #obal #cara {
        background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #336;
        display: table-cell;
    }
    #cara .inner {
        width: 10px;
    }
    div#druhy {
        background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #393;
        display: table-cell;
        font-size: 1rem;
        height: 100%;
        width: 120px;
    }
    div#prvni .inner, div#druhy .inner {
        padding: 10px;
    }
```

===================== HTML =============================

```
<div id="obal">
    <div id="prvni">
        <div class="inner">Prvni cast text neni sice nejsilnejsi, ale spisovatel se snazi popsat dulezite body jeho navstevy
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="cara">
        <div class="inner"></div>
    </div>
    <div id="druhy">
        <div class="inner">Druha cast mluvila hlavne o velkych problemech na startu, kdy se vsichni ucastnici nestihnuli pripravit a pote nasledovat zmatek. Jenze kazdy chtel vyhrat, tak to nevzdal <br> NIKDY :-)
         </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set the height to 100vh

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

http://jsfiddle.net/Ls6sqz2n/

You'd needed to add `height: 100%;` to the element ancestors, including `html` and `body`:

```
html, body {
    height: 100%;
}

#obal {
    margin: 10px;
    height: 200px;
    height: 100%;
}

#cara {
    position: relative;
    width: 10px;
    height: 100%;
    float: left;
}   
#cara .inner {
    position: absolute;
    right: 15px;
    height: 100%;
    width: 10px;
    background: #336;
}
```

(...)

Comment: I do not know that column will be longer. I can not set up height cara > inner as same as druhy > inner. Height of cara I want to have same as height of longer column. Not height cara 100% of body.

Answer (score 0):

[Using #obal as a reference](http://jsfiddle.net/p47uqLh1/) for #cara relative height:

```
#obal {
    margin: 10px;
    position: relative; overflow: hidden; 
}

#cara {
    float: left;
    margin-left: -20px;
}   
#cara .inner {
    position: absolute;
    width: 10px; height: 100%;
    background: #336;
}
```

(...)

From the [specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visudet.html#the-height-property):

> The percentage is calculated with
>   respect to the height of the generated box's containing block. **If the
>   height of the containing block is not specified explicitly** (i.e., it
>   depends on content height), **and this element is not absolutely
>   positioned, the value computes to 'auto'**.

---

[Using an `overflow: hidden` to cut](http://jsfiddle.net/quf3xy8d/4/) the line with a huge height:

```
#obal {
    margin: 10px;
    overflow: hidden;
}

#cara {
    float: left;
    position: relative; right: 20px;
}   
#cara .inner {
    position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0;
    width: 10px; height: 10000px;
    background: #336;
}
```

(...)

Using [flex](http://jsfiddle.net/e431jg98/):

```
#obal {
    margin: 10px;
    display: flex;
}

#prvni, #druhy {
    display: table;
}
```